Can you write a script that contains both bash (or sh) and powershell (or cmd, bat) so the same file can be executed on Win and *nix?
I have a script that needs to run on Windows, Linux and MacOS.
I know Windows determines how to run a script by using the file extension, where *nix will use the #!.
I'm hoping there is enough syntax overlap that I can use an if statement to redirect & run a platform specific subscript.
Essentially something like this flow:
This is entry.ps1 that assumes powershell 7+ (that's the default on Windows 10, right?) and bash
#!/bin/sh      <-- ignored by powershell
$SHELL = "" && & ".\main.ps1" || ./main.sh


You're asking about running a bash shell but your hashbang uses /bin/sh. Not necessarily the same program and, even if /bin/sh links to /bin/bash, bash operates differently when called as sh.

Line 2 is also badly wrong. Are you trying to set SHELL to an empty string or check to see if SHELL is empty? The line is wrong in either case. Using shellcheck is often recommended.

Sorry, I am not fussy about the interpreter, I am just trying to find enough overlap between two shell environments that ship with Windows/Linux to fork off and run a script dedicated to that platform. The code is just an example, it doesn't work. I tried to mash a powershell 7 with shell (unsuccessfully)

about the best you can do is attempt to exploit the similarities between the shells, store the actual script code in strings, and dynamically execute them, but it does rely on the ability to identify the shell you are in in a cross-platform manner, since that is the one piece of the code that absolutely must run as-is in both shells. I can't help but feel like this is a fools errand. do you have a specific reason to want to do something like this, or is it just somthing you want to try?

A useful search term is "polyglot". https://github.com/llamasoft/polyshell and https://cspotcode.com/posts/polyglot-powershell-and-bash-script are some examples that might provide some inspiration.

This looks like classic XY problem. Why do you need a single file? If it's for some tool, e.g. VSCode's dev containers would be an example, I don't think it's even worth spending time thinking about this.
